# How to create binary text encoded stream in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I found AV_CODEC_ID_BINTEXT as valid CODEC_ID in FFMPEG. But I found that there is only decoder for AV_CODEC_ID_BINTEXT [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/libavformat_2bintext_8c_source.html)
Why is there not an encoder for AV_CODEC_ID_BINTEXT or in general for "Data Stream"? Whats the expectation of the binary text decoder shipped out of FFMPEG?

Comment: There are no data encoders present in ffmpeg. What's the proposed use case?

Comment: I am trying to add a binary data stream along with video stream using FFMPEG. I suppose I could add this binary stream as a subtitle stream. But with subtitles, its difficult to synchronize the data associated with each of the frames as its timestamp based. Is there a way to store per video frame additional binary data?